# Estimate Most Focused Image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-analysis

I am trying to find the image which has the optimum focus of a focus stack (10 images). I am able to find the best two images by using the minimum gray intensity values but now the problematic part comes.

All standard methods fail because I have a very strong background with sharp edges which are laying under my object, the green cell.

Best image for human eye:

[image: Best image for human eye]

Best image choose by CV methods:

[image: Best image choose by CV methods]

I tried already many things like FFT, filters, edge detection but most of the time it fails...

Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: why don’t you use the colors?

Comment: Because sometimes the dye is leaking outside the cell...This is a nice example but it's not always so clear.

Comment: But would it help most of the time? Automation or people are never perfect

Comment: Not really...If you look at the example above in the second image, those strong structures also appear inside the green cell (upper cell wall), which means any method would favor the second image...

Comment: You might want to look at lightfield cameras. You can set the focal plane computationally. There is an interesting literature on computational photography. I don’t have enough experience with it to know if having multiple focal planes can be used

Comment: Do you mean something like acquiring several focal planes? We are using the  Axio Scan.Z1 which creates a z-stack with x images (10 in our case). Above I show only two out of ten.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68385/discussion-between-snowflake-and-stanley-pawlukiewicz).

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem? Is it still relevant?

Comment: Not really and yes it is still relevant

Comment: Hi @snowflake, can you share what the "standard" approaches are? I'm totally noob into image processing, but have a similar problem where I'm given 5-6 photos per page and need to figure out the most "focused" one (it's not easy to do with my eyes!), so I am after some tool which might calculate "focusness" (maybe?)